# Python can find a module....and then it can't

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python, python-module

I am finally going full steam into Python, but for some reason I have an issue where Python can find a module in the interactive CLI and then it can't when I write a script. The module is specifically mysql.connector located in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages .  As you can see from the interactive CLI session, it imports mysql.connector just fine. Echoing the sys.path shows 'Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'

Here's a new CLI window (I'm on a Mac 10.10). Note: initially when I login I am popped into my home dir which of course is normal.

```
wilkie:~ wilkie$ which python
/usr/bin/python
wilkie:~ wilkie$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle-5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

So I merely changed to another directory...

```
cd /Users/wilkie/Projects/dataparse
```

and just like that... it can't find mysql.connector

```
wilkie:dataparse wilkie$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle-5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named connector
>>>
```

I am officially stumped and have no idea why this is happening. Anyone ever encounter this?

Comment: how did you install it? What does `import mysql;mysql.__file__` output?

Comment: Do you have a module called `mysql.py` in your `dataparse` directory?

Comment: Please do a `cd /Users/wilkie/Projects/dataparse` and then the `ls` command and let us know what the output is.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: when it works: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/__init__.py'

Comment: @JaneWIlkie, and from the non-working directory? Make sure to only `import mysql`

Comment: OMG! I can't believe I did this: guys, I'm so sorry but RussellBorogove and puzzlepalace turned the light on! My script that I am trying to test is named mysql.py ! D'oh! Just needed to rename it.

Comment: @JaneWIlkie, delete any .pyc file also or you will have the same problem again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the traceback, I see that you named your file `mysql.py`. Therefore, when you try to import something from `mysql.py`, the interpreter looks for it in your own script, not the "actual" module. Instead of casting a wider net, it immediately gives up. To fix this, rename your script to something that doesn't mask any module names.

Comment: Your answer is exactly correct, don't know why you were downvoted.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's a mystery to me too why you were down voted. I can tell you Ethan that before I voted you to 0 you were at -1 too and that didn't make sense since you had the correct answer also.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `mysql` something or other either in your home directory, or in your new directory.  It might be a `.py` file or perhaps the actual package (in the wrong place ;).  Fix that and your problem should go away.